# Ionic virtual scroll list elements always blink when data set being changed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic virtual scroll and infinite scroll to display my items list, it works fine but I notice that whenever it fetches data from server, the list element will blink a moment, I guess it's because virtual scroll is re-rendering the html elements. If I just used `ngFor` to display the item list, there would not be any blink but it cannot display too much items properly like more than 200. This is kind of annoying and I want to remove that blink on virtual scroll, how can I do that?

```html
<div style="height: 100%">
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="list | pesStatus: statusFilter" [approxItemHeight]="'108px'" [virtualTrackBy]="trackBy">

  <ion-item *virtualItem="let item">
    <ion-row class="pes-info-title">
      <ion-col class="pull-side">
        <div>{{item.TrackingNumber}}</div>
        <div>{{item.BusinessPartnerName}}</div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="pull-side">
        <div>
          <svg-icon width="16px" height="16px" [id]="'svg-icon-status' + item.PesStatusId"></svg-icon>
          <div class="pes-info-small">{{item.StatusName}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pes-info-small">{{item.PesCode}}</div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="pull-side">
        <div>
          <svg-icon width="16px" height="16px" [id]="'svg-icon-status' + item.PesStatusId"></svg-icon>
          <div class="pes-info-small">{{item.DateDelivered}}</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="pes-info-small">{{item.ProjectName}}</div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
      
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
 <ion-infinite-scroll #infiniteScroll
    (ionInfinite)="$event.waitFor(doInfinite($event))">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingText="Loading..."></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with the virtual scroll in ionic.
see https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11788

You should have shared how you append data from the server, and further details about the filter.

**Mainly this issue is related to the way you push new data into your array.**

**DO NOT** use concatenate(or spread operator) because it will replace the current array and cause a full refresh of the virtual scroll. I solved this issue by iterating over the rows, and pushing them one by one to the array.

```
// WRONG WAY will CAUSE BLINKS AND JUMPS
gotData(_data:any[]){
   this.list = this.list.concat(_data); // will cause the issue.
}


// CORRECT WAY TO SOLVE THE BLINKING ISSUE
gotData(_data:any[]){

 let len:number = _data.length;

for(let i:number = 0; i< len; i++)
 this.list.push(_data[i]); // this will work without blinks or jumps
}
```

I have solved the issue with infinite scroller and virtual list by applying this fix.